# Show UITableView editing mode options on the right

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewcelleditcontrol

I have a tableView implemented similar to the screenshot which I set the editing to true when the view is loaded up. This is to allow the user to have multiple selection option already available for them.

My problem is that I'd like to show the editing option (the round selection buttons) on the right as opposed to the usual iOS style on the left (which is how my app is atm) but I'd like to achieve what is shown in this screenshot. Anyone can advise on how to achieve that?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have this as a checkbox within your cell's UI and handle the display (with or without animation) yourself. I'd add an `isEditing` flag in your tableview model items that handles that state.

Another approach would be to try reverting to RTL for that particular screen. Haven't tried that ever though and I would not recommend having something like that in production code.

`[UITableView appearance].semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft;`

or

`self.tableView.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft;`

That will most likely send the letter section to the left as well though.